# Circuit that can replace the ideal current source in the two stage amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, current-source

I want to find a circuit that can replace the ideal current source in the two stage amp,my classmate said that i can use the bandgap to replace it,but i want to make sure of it,doesn't bandgap provide a stable voltage?why can it be a current source?so can anyone give me a suggestion?

I also find a circuit from here:

[Replacing Ideal current source in two-stage opamp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223785/replacing-ideal-current-source-in-two-stage-opamp)

but honestly,i don't know how to calculate it,so i can't use it to replace the ideal current source

Comment: It's not very difficult to find designs for current sources online or in books like https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521809266/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510395261&sr=8-1&keywords=Art+of+Electronics

Comment: You are probably looking for a "current mirror"

Comment: @Matt but the current mirror also need a ideal current source

Comment: @ShineSun It does not. You can establish a reference current with a resistor: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Simple_MOSFET_mirror.PNG